# AxesGrid with imshow : do plots have to have the same extent?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using the AxesGrid class to make a plot that looks like this one : [image: AxesGrid with imshow and contour]

The code basically looks like this :

```
      grid = AxesGrid(fig,
                111,
                nrows_ncols = (2,2),
                axes_pad = 0.50,
                label_mode = "all",
                cbar_location='right',
                cbar_mode='single',
                cbar_pad =0.3,
                cbar_size='5%'
                )
```

and then for each of the 4 panels I call imshow and contour like this :

```
       # some definitions etc.


        im1 = grid[0].imshow(np.transpose(De[i1:i2,j1:j2]),
           aspect='equal',
           vmin=vmin, vmax = vmax,
           origin='lower',
           extent=extent)


    # some other stuff [...]


        grid[0].contour(np.transpose(F[i1:i2,j1:j2]),levels=levls,
                extent=extent,colors='k',cmap=None)

    # and so on for the 3 other panels
```

The only difference is that now, I'd like the images to have different value for the extent keyword. 
Say I want the upper right image to have an extent of (31.5,35.5,11,14) and the lower right panel to have an extent of (29.5, 33.5, 11, 14), I get this :

[image: new plot]

It seems that matplotlib adjusts the axes. Is there a way to specify the extent I'd like and not have the empty white space between my data and the axe ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the parameter:

```
share_x=False
```

To your Grid generation.  Then you can set the xlim of each plot individually.